# ubuntu:22.04 docker image doesn't find alternative certificate subject name for 'raw.githubusercontent.com'

Tags: github, ssl, curl, dockerfile, ubuntu-22.04

There is a bug in ubuntu:22.04 I can't seem to pinpoint. If you try to build the following dockerfile you get the error list below. It successfully builds if you use ubuntu:23.04.

## Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y curl

RUN curl -fsSL -v https://raw.githubusercontent.com/
```

## Error

```
Step 3/3 : RUN curl -v https://raw.githubusercontent.com/
 ---> Running in dba578e366fd
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 185.199.108.133:443...
* Connected to raw.githubusercontent.com (185.199.108.133) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.0 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Finished (20):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [19 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [3050 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
{ [264 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [52 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Finished (20):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [52 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=*.github.io
*  start date: Feb 21 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 20 23:59:59 2024 GMT
*  subjectAltName does not match raw.githubusercontent.com
* SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'raw.githubusercontent.com'
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [193 bytes data]
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Supplemental data (23):
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, close notify (256):
} [2 bytes data]
curl: (60) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'raw.githubusercontent.com'
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I tested the dockerfile with ubuntu:23.04 and it works. I also confirmed it works on a server running ubuntu 22.04 LTS. That makes me believe it is a docker/image issue.

If you run `curl -v https://raw.githubusercontent.com/` locally it also works and finds the cert SAN.

If you run `echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername raw.githubusercontent.com -connect raw.githubusercontent.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -text` you can see that the SAN is present in the cert.

```
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:*.github.io, DNS:github.io, DNS:*.github.com, DNS:github.com, DNS:www.github.com, DNS:*.githubusercontent.com, DNS:githubusercontent.com`
```

Confirmed this works aswell. `docker run -it --rm curlimages/curl:7.81.0 curl -v https://raw.githubusercontent.com/`